# Creating a matrix under conditions

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, expression-construction, constraint

I would like to create a matrix whose elements satisfy the following conditions ( *Mathematica* 9 )

```
a[1,1] < a[1,2] < a[1,3];
a[1,2] = 2;
a[2,1] > a[3,1];
a[4,2] < a[4,3];
a[3,5] < a[4,5] < a[5,5];
a[5,1] = 4;
```

and in each row and and column we must have numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 exactly once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A latin square generator([source](http://richard-craig.co.uk/code/create-a-latin-square-in-matlab-20111006)):

```
ls[perm_] := Module[{n = Length[perm], mat},
  mat = Transpose[Join[{perm}, ConstantArray[1, {n - 1, n}]]];
  (Mod[Accumulate@# - 1, n] 1 & /@ mat) + 1
  ]
```

Generating candidates:

```
cand = ls /@ Permutations[Range[5]];
```

Criteria:

```
crit[mt_] := 
 And[mt[[1, 1]] < mt[[1, 2]] < mt[[1, 3]], mt[[1, 2]] == 2, 
  mt[[2, 1]] > mt[[3, 1]], mt[[4, 2]] < mt[[4, 3]], 
  mt[[3, 5]] < mt[[4, 5]] < mt[[5, 5]], mt[[5, 1]] == 4]
```

Search:

```
Cases[{#, crit@#} & /@ cand, {x_, True} :> MatrixForm[x]]
```

yields:

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, `ls /@ Permutations[Range[5]]` produces only 120 of all latin squares, right? If so, you are lucky that one of those satisfies criteria.

Comment: @enzotib yes that is correct...(i) I did actually originally permute rows and columns as well and the answer was the only result, it was clear the smaller search space would suffice for answer to drop out(ii)I presented this as though lucky in the sense you describe, it is not unreasonable to see if there is a solution in small search of space (iii) I make and made no claim of exhaustive look though there are 56 reduced forms and 161280 overall. Would be happy for other answers

Answer (score 3):

This was done in verion 10.02, but it *should* work in V 9

```
a = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    {5, 3, 1, 2, 4},
    {2, 4, 5, 3, 1},
    {3, 1, 4, 5, 2},
    {4, 5, 2, 1, 3}};
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: we must have also the numbers from 1 to 5 exactly once in each row and column.

Comment: I just spit-laughed my tea. +1

Comment: @asad I think it is ok now.

Comment: @Nasser, thanks, but I would like to write the code to create a Matrix in Mathematica with some conditions not necessarily the final answer.

Answer (score 3):

I first build the matrix with the "1 to 5 exactly once" condition.
This is done row by row, each row from the list of permutations having no slot in common with the previous.
Then check the given conditions:

```
a = Table[0, {5}, {5}];
cond := a[[1, 2]] == 2 &&
   a[[5, 1]] == 4 &&
   a[[1, 1]] == 1 &&
   a[[1, 1]] < a[[1, 2]] < a[[1, 3]] &&
   a[[2, 1]] > a[[3, 1]] &&
   a[[4, 2]] < a[[4, 3]] &&
   a[[3, 5]] < a[[4, 5]] < a[[5, 5]];
d[r1_, r2_] := Min[Abs[r1 - r2]];
p[1] = Permutations[Range[5]];
n[1] = Length[p[1]];
While[True,
 a[[1]] = p[1][[RandomInteger[{1, n[1]}]]];
 ok = True;
 Do[
   p[i] = Select[p[i - 1], d[#, a[[i - 1]]] > 0 &];
   n[i] = Length[p[i]];
   If[! (ok = (n[i] > 0)), Break[]];
   a[[i]] = p[i][[RandomInteger[{1, n[i]}]]],
   {i, 2, 5}
   ];
 If[! ok, Continue[]];
 If[! cond, Continue[]];
 Break[]
 ]

a // MatrixForm
```